# Is TRESOR included in the latest kernel?

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel

Did [TRESOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRESOR) get included in the
mainline Linux kernel? Where would I look to find out? Is there any documentation describing its use? Reading about [cold boot attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack) on Wikipedia makes me think TRESOR would be essential to having reasonably secure dm-crypt+LUKS system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From searching the [Linux kernel cross-reference](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6.7/), seems that no (gives 0 results). However, from [TRESOR](http://www1.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/tresor)'s page, you can [find a patch for kernel 3.6.2](http://www1.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/filepool/projects/tresor/tresor-patch-3.6.2_aesni) and the [documentation](http://www1.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/tresor?q=content/readme).

Answer (score 3):

TRESOR is still an out of tree kernel module today. Further, it looks like it is no longer being developed by the people at Erlangen.

I co-maintain some AUR packages which have updated TRESOR up to the current 3.17 and 3.14 kernels:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-tresor/

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-lts-tresor/